# JW Player unable to display flv served via File Handler (.ashx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, flv, jwplayer, ashx

I'm trying to load an flv file into JWPlayer via an ashx page.  However I always get the following error:

> Task Queue failed at step 5: Playlist could not be loaded: Playlist
>   file did not contain a valid playlist

If I load the ashx page directly in Firefox the video will load and automatically play.  If I change flvplayer to point directly to an flvfile it works fine.  So I'm slightly baffled as to what the problem is!  One thing I have noticed is that when playing directly therough the browser the code behind the ashx page is run twice, and the second time no session variables are available, although Fiddler only detects one request from the browser.  When JWPlayer calls the ashx page, the code is only executed one time.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="CourseVideoHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.IO;

public class CourseVideoHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {


        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ContentType = "video/x-flv";

        FileStream fs = File.Open(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/content/coursevideos/rowthe boat.flv"),
                                  FileMode.Open);

        byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, (int) fs.Length);
        fs.Close();

        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}


<!-- START OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING TO COPY-PASTE -->
    <div id="mediaplayer">JW Player goes here</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            file: "../../CourseVideoHandler.ashx?t=.flv",
            image: "preview.jpg"
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any JS error?
Have you checked on other browsers?

Also there is an issue with special characters on the jwplayer:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/8976/using-ashx-as-image-and-video-params

It is a little old, but you can check it anyways.